# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'requisition_id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: laravel-5.4

Hi following are my relations.

SubmitApplication.php

```
public function requisition()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Requisition::class);
}
```

Requisition.php

```
public function submitApplication()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(SubmitApplication::class);
}
```

My blade

```
<form class="btn-group" action="{{ route('requisitions.update', ['id' => $requisition->id]) }}" method="post">
    {{ method_field('PATCH') }}
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">تایید</button>
</form>
```

RequisitionController.php

```
public function update(Request $request, SubmitApplication $submitApplication)
{
    $submitApplication->approved = 1;
    $submitApplication->save();
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

For requisitions table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('requisitions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('school_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('type');
        $table->string('status');
        $table->string('date');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('school_id')->references('id')->on('schools');
    });
}
```

For submit_applications table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('submit_applications', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('requisition_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('school_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('approved');
        $table->string('application');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('requisition_id')->references('id')->on('requisitions');
        $table->foreign('school_id')->references('id')->on('schools');
    });
}
```

RequisitionController.php

```
public function update(Request $request, SubmitApplication $submitApplication)
{
    $submitApplication->approved = 1;
    $submitApplication->save();
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

I Get this error.

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'requisition_id' doesn't
>   have a default value (SQL: insert into `submit_applications`
>   (`approved`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, 2018-06-18
>   04:22:48, 2018-06-18 04:22:48))

When I click approved button. it added. id do not want add

[image: Databasse]

Maybe am I doing wrong?

Comment: Set default value in your migration file to 'requisition_id' field

Comment: How to i am doing it?

Comment: Can you please update your migration file method up code in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **submit_applications** table, set nullable to **requisition_id**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('submit_applications', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('requisition_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
        $table->integer('school_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
        $table->integer('approved')->nullable(true);
        $table->string('application')->nullable(true);
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('requisition_id')->references('id')->on('requisitions');
        $table->foreign('school_id')->references('id')->on('schools');
    });
}
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'application' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `submit_applications` (`approved`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, 2018-06-18 05:47:51, 2018-06-18 05:47:51))

Comment: Update my answer, set default value or nullable(true) if your fields are optional

Comment: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`prj_tvto`.`submit_applications`, CONSTRAINT `submit_applications_requisition_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`requisition_id`) REFERENCES `requisitions` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `submit_applications` (`approved`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, 2018-06-18 06:04:17, 2018-06-18 06:04:17))

Comment: Update answer, try nullable, if you don't provide values for foreign key added fields

Comment: if you problem is solved, please accept answer and for another issue please submit another question